# suspend doesn't work on battery mode (but it does while charging)

Tags: suspend, 18.04, xps

I have a XPS 9550 running a fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04

My problem is when I try to suspend my machine while on battery mode. It just turn off the machine.

The most strange thing is that it do works perfectly when I'm charging it (AC power plugged in).

Any clue about what can I change or do to fix this?

Note, my battery works fine, and it's fully charged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue with my Asus UX303UA by updating the BIOS.

Maybe you have an available update for your hardware.

regards

Aerlai

Answer (score 1):

For XPS 9550, there is the latest BIOS version (1.7.0), published on the 4th of May [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/it/it/itbsdt1/product-support/product/xps-15-9550-laptop/drivers). I have zero problem with it.